# symfony1 403 Forbidden error for certain actions

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

In my symfony1 project, I need to create a url to get a list of owners.
I created a route in routing.yml that looks like this:

```
#owner
owner_list:
    url: /:id/owner/list.:sf_format
    param: { module: owner, action: list }
    requirements:
        sf_format: (?:json)
```

I then added a folder 'owner' to the 'modules' folder of my project folder within the 'apps' directory.
I added a folder 'actions' and a file 'actions.class.php' to that folder.

My actions class looks something like this:

`class ownerActions extends sfActions
{`

```
    /**
     * Executes list action
     *
     * @param sfRequest $request A request object
     */
public function executeList(sfWebRequest $request)
    {...
$this->getResponse()->setContentType('application/json');
        $this->getResponse()->setContent(json_encode($this->owners));
return sfView::NONE;    }    }
```

When I go to the url `http://website/project/id/owner/list.json`, it should go to the new action that I created and output the json.
Instead it gives me a 403 error.

There are many other actions within this project that are created the same way and I am able to access.

Any ideas why and how I can fix this?

Comment: Which url do you call? Can you paste the beginning of your actions.class.php, where you define the class name.

Comment: please see my code update in the question

Comment: What about security settings for your application? Is this action secured or not? And just to be sure: your module folder is inside `apps/frontend/` not inside `apps`? (I mean it is inside a specific application's dir)

Comment: yes it is inside the application's dir.    security.yml looks like this    `default:
  is_secure: false
settings:
  is_secure: false`

Comment: I am adding to a project that someone else started. They have many actions and some can be accessed and some give the same 403 error. My question is what would be different about different actions and how to make mine like those that allow access?

Comment: Post an answer and accept it instead of updating your question with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution.
Needed to add:
`options: restricted: false`
to my route

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
url: /:id/owner/list.:sf_format
```

But the called url is

```
/id/owner/list.json
```

Should there be an id (I guess numeric) instead of the literal "id"?

And I haven't tried myself but will the routing accept a variable parameter as first url element?
What is the output of your [appname]_dev.php when calling this?

Comment: 'id' is the value for ':id' and 'json' is the value for ':sf_format'   I have some routes that are created in the same way and do work, so my real question is why some actions are accessible and some give the 403 error.